# Why am I getting InvalidClientTokenId Error in aws-cli?

Tags: aws-cli, saml-2.0

I've configured an AWS profile to try and run the cs-suite Scout2 report but I keep getting an InvalidClientTokenId when running the following command

```
[------------- cs-suite]$ sudo python cs.py -env aws

An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the ListAccountAliases operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "cs.py", line 117, in <module>
    main()

  File "cs.py", line 67, in main
    from modules import awsaudit

  File "/home/i28352/cs-suite/modules/awsaudit.py", line 30, in <module>
    account_name = get_account_alias() or get_account_id()

  File "/home/i28352/cs-suite/modules/awsaudit.py", line 14, in get_account_alias
    account_details = subprocess.check_output(['aws iam list-account-aliases'],shell=True)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['aws iam list-account-aliases']' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

I've run sudo python setup.py, copied over my access keys and ensured they were correct. Our enterprise uses Okta for authentication

Comment: I can see that your are trying to run the command on the shell. How have you configured your aws credentials. Did u put it in a config/credential file in the .aws folder. Or are you setting them somewhere in your code or environment variable??

Comment: I set them manually through the cli. would this have an effect on the account?

Comment: When you say you did it manually, does that mean the keys were stored in the .aws folder in the credentials/config file or were they just set up as variables for your session. If it was the latter, your sub process would have no visibility of those credentials

Comment: I'm not really sure how, but removing root access by executing 'sudo chown -R <account> cs-suite' fixed the issue.